# Make ansible read from folders on current user

Tags: linux, ansible

I'm looking for a way to make `ansible` read a file from a certain location regardless of user (i.e. I would like to make the scripts usable for any user).

Unfortunately, `ansible` seems to like hard-coded paths: `/home/user/foo/bar.yml` works; `~/foo/bar.yml` does not work.

I've tried to use these variants (none of which seem to work):

```
- import_playbook: ~/Documents/foo/bar.yml
```

```
- import_playbook: "{{ lookup('env','USER') }}/Documents/foo/bar.yml"
```

```
- import_playbook: "/home/{{ lookup('env','USER') }}/Documents/foo/bar.yml"
```

How can I achieve making `ansible` read the from a given directory regardless of user? I'd like these scripts to be executable for anyone.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Ideally, I'd like to make the script executed by the current user, too: e.g. `become_user: current` (don't know if the latter command is possible to use).

Comment: I have the feeling that within your description some context is missing. Are the playbooks executed locally or remotely. Is the playbook calling user the as on the remote side? Etc. I've solved this kind of requirement with a script under `/etc/profile.d` and `ACCOUNT=$(who am i | cut -d " " -f 1)`. Command `ansible-playbook --user=${ACCOUNT} ...`, as well the variable in playbooks `{{ ansible_user }}`. So I can use contructs like `/home/{{ ansible_user }}/directory` or `/home/${ACCOUNT}/directory`.

Comment: Pardon the late answer. The script is meant to be run by anyone who wants to use it, independent of username. I am mainly deploying it locally, on my own machine (not SSH or anything).